# Signing Apps Taking Forever

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to increase the work flow of my app deployment. From building to signing to getting it onto app it can take anywhere up to 40mins. What advice can somebody give me on:

1) Speeding up compile time
2) Speeding up the archive process
3) Speeding up the code signing

thanks

Comment: What are the times for 1, 2, 3.

Comment: I released a 600mb app several months ago, and the archiving stage took roughly a minute, I agree with @Joe, it might be time to consider upgrading the computer.

Comment: 500Mb is the .app file or the project folder size ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to consider are the size of resources. Can any resources such as videos or images be compressed and still usable? Are there a large number of files that could be compressed into a zip file and then unzipped on first launch? Also check and make sure you do not have any long running custom scripts in the build process. After you've determined that resources or a build configuration setting is not an issue then I would advise investing in a faster computer (more RAM and **processing power**) if you are running on older hardware.

Comment: My 2008 MacPro is way faster now that I upgraded to 4GB from 2 GB. RAM can make a huge difference if you're near the limit on OSX.

Comment: @Asheh before jumping and making a big purchase I also recommend profiling your computer for i/o access, CPU utilization and RAM access. It is possible that something such as an antivirus application is slowing things down.

Answer (score 2):

For reference, my early 2009 2.93GHz C2D iMac with 8GB RAM can archive and sign a 2GB application in approximately 15-20 minutes.  My late 2011 1.8GHz i7 MacBook Air can do it significantly faster.  40 minutes for a 500MB application seems far too slow unless there is something else bogging down your system.  Try checking your disk with Disk Utility and seeing what else is running with Activity Monitor.

Answer (score 1):

The rarely changed code could be imported to the libraries (maybe with the help of additional projects not to produce many targets), that dramatically increases the compilation speed while the signing and archiving is usually faster than the build itself.